# Restore DB2 10.5 FixPackge 10 to DB2 11.5 failed

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I have a database file backup from DB2 10.5 fix package 10, Now I do want to restore it into DB2 11.5 developer edition to do a test.
But got below issue:

> SQL2519N  The database was restored but the restored database was not
>   upgraded to the current release.  Error "-440" with tokens "SQLERRM
>   FUNCTION " is returned.

I use below commands, both no success.

```
db2 restore database DBNAME01 from /tmp/backups without prompting

db2 restore database DBNAME01 from /tmp/backups replace existing
```

When I try to use:

```
db2 restore database DBNAME01 from /tmp/backups
```

I got:

> ```
> >     SQL0440N  No authorized routine named "SQLERRM" of type "FUNCTION" having
> >     compatible arguments was found.  LINE NUMBER=1.  SQLSTATE=42884
> ```

Can someone help?

Comment: Compare the registry-settings of the source (v10.5.0.10) Db2-instance with those of the Db2 v11.5 instance, and ensure they are compatible (bounce the v11.5 instance if you make changes) .Next, when you retry the restore and get SQL2519N, examine the *new* messages that are in db2diag.log, and then EDIT your question to add them (don't include them in comments).

Comment: Do you have the system date set correctly? Sometimes you may see such errors on system functions absence due to this. If yes, then you should open a Case with IBM support on this.

Comment: Thanks both mao and mark, should be the compatible issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can only restore from offline backup; try this.

Comment: Was you answer shot?